# implementing parse push notification at eclipse project

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

i am trying to use parse push service at my eclipse project but considering there is no **build.gradle** i cant do that and i get errors. is it even possible to use it at eclipse? how?
this is all for android studio : https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

> Blockquote
>   The type bolts.Task cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Parse.com libraries in an Eclipse project.

To do this, you have to add all Parse Libries and .jar files aswell as the bolts depencies

1. Download Parse SDK, in there you find a lot of files (Parse-1.xx-javadoc, ParseTwitterUtils-1.xxx, ParseCrashReporting, etc etc)

Add al the files starting with 'Parse-[ for the lastest version to your project

This is the same as doing this in android studio:

```
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
```

2. In the Parse SDK folder, there should also be a Bolts Library jar files( bolts-android-1.2.1-***), add these to the project aswell

this is the same as doing this in android studio:

```
     compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
```

Now you should have both the Parse & Bolts dependencies

On a sidenote, I can really advice upgrading to Android Studio if you can.